# Admin Notices don't display on the admin screen for certain post

Tags: posts, theme-development, post-thumbnails, notices

I want to make a featured image required. For starters i am trying to show an error message after update or post buttons are pressed. The problem is that the notices which i try to include don't show up. For example

```
function my_admin_notice(){
    global $pagenow;
    if ( $pagenow == 'post.php' ) {
        echo '<div class="updated">
             <p>This notice only appears on the plugins page.</p>
         </div>';
    }
}
add_action('admin_notices', 'my_admin_notice');
```

Whatever notice i try to display in specific post admin screen it doesn't show. Could the problem be in the new Gutenberg editor?

**Edit:** Yes, when Gutenberg is active the notices don't show up. If i add filter to block the editor, then the messages are displayed. So, how can i make notices to shows in the Gutenberg editor too?

Comment: This is because your code shows an admin notice at the top of the page on a new page request, but Gutenberg uses REST API endpoints to save the post, not a form submission/page request

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Notices in the Block Editor would require JavaScript code.

```
   ( function( wp ) {
    wp.data.dispatch('core/notices').createNotice(
        'error', // Can be one of: success, info, warning, error.
        'Error Message.', // Text string to display.
        {
            isDismissible: true, // Whether the user can dismiss the notice.
            // Any actions the user can perform.
            actions: [
                {
                    url: '#',
                    label: 'View post'
                }
            ]
        }
    );
} )( window.wp );
```

**Link: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/notices/**

Comment: How do you call this from php so the snackbar is shown? I can't find an example anywhere....